# php: array sort by string key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How can I sort a array like this by its keys, from the smaller resolution to the larger one:

```
$sizes = array(
   '120x120' => 'large',
   '60x60' => 'small',
   '200x200' => 'very large',
   '90x90' => 'medium',
...
```

?

should be :

- 60x60
- 90x90
- 120x120
- 200x200
- ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[**`ksort()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) **in numeric mode** should work just fine :

```
$sizes = array(
   '120x120' => 'large',
   '60x60' => 'small',
   '200x200' => 'very large',
   '90x90' => 'medium',
);

ksort($sizes, SORT_NUMERIC);
var_dump($sizes);
```

will get you :

```
array
  '60x60' => string 'small' (length=5)
  '90x90' => string 'medium' (length=6)
  '120x120' => string 'large' (length=5)
  '200x200' => string 'very large' (length=10)
```

This will work because the size is a numeric -- and is found before the `'x'` *(not sure what will be done with the `'x'` and what follows -- but, anyway, that part of the keys is useless, as it's purely redondant information)*

Comment: thank you, I didn't think sorting by numbers would work because I have a `x` there :)

Comment: @Alexandra PHP will effectively truncate the "number" when it hits the 'x'. As such, you're only really sorting on the first number.

Comment: this doesn't work as it will sort as string so that 12 would be before 6 because it starts with 1, right?

Answer (score 9):

you need natural sort by keys, can use [uksort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php)

```
uksort($array, 'strnatcasecmp');
```

Comment: I believe this is a better answer, as well as being more general purpose. This will sort '120x120', '120x90' properly whereas numeric key sort would not.

Answer (score 2):

Try with [ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).

> Sorts an array by key, maintaining key
>   to data correlations. This is useful
>   mainly for associative arrays.

Edit: to make the answer complete, please do use the `SORT_NUMERIC` flag.

Comment: -1 That does not work try to understand question  output `[120x120] => large
    [200x200] => very large
    [60x60] => small
    [90x90] => medium
`

Comment: these are strings and will not get sorted like integers

Answer (score 2):

```
$sizes = array(
   '120x120' => 'large',
   '60x60' => 'small',
   '200x200' => 'very large',
   '90x90' => 'medium');
uksort($sizes, 'userSorting');
print_r($sizes);
function userSorting($a, $b) {
    $a = explode('x', $a);
    $b = explode('x', $b);
    return $a[0] > $b[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at PHP's [Sorting Arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) manual page, you can see there are a few options for sorting the array based on its keys, of which [ksort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) (using the `SORT_NUMERIC` modifier) is most likely the one you're after.

Comment: @Alexandra Apologies - you need to use the `SORT_NUMERIC` modifier to ksort. @Pascal's superior answer illustrates this perfectly. :-)